# Algorithm to parse collection and trim it based on various properties

Tags: algorithm

```
public class PCE
{
        public string ActivityType { get; set; }
        public string ActivitySubtype { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }            
}

public class ActionLimit
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
    public int Nos { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of PCE. Say -

```
            PCE pce = new PCE();
            pce.ActivityType = "Sales";
            pce.ActivitySubtype = "Loan2";
            pce.Id = 1;
            listPCE.Add(pce);

            pce = new PCE();
            pce.ActivityType = "Sales";
            pce.ActivitySubtype = "Loan1";
            pce.Id = 2;
            listPCE.Add(pce);

            pce = new PCE();
            pce.ActivityType = "Sales";
            pce.ActivitySubtype = "Subcat";
            pce.Id = 3;
            listPCE.Add(pce);

            pce = new PCE();
            pce.ActivityType = "Loyalty";
            pce.ActivitySubtype = "Loan";
            pce.Id = 4;
            listPCE.Add(pce);
```

And I have a collection of ActionLimits. Say -

```
        ActionLimit al = new ActionLimit();
        al.PropertyName = "ActivityType";
        al.PropertyValue = "Sales";
        al.Nos = 2;
        listActionLimit.Add(al);

        al = new ActionLimit();
        al.PropertyName = "ActivitySubtype";
        al.PropertyValue = "Loan";
        al.Nos = 1;
        listActionLimit.Add(al);
```

Problem statement: I need the algo to limit the collection of PCEs by ActionLimit "Nos" property. In the above example, I need to limits PCEs by 2 Sales ActivityType and 1 Loan ActivitySubtype. The algo needs to generic enough for any property of PCE (not just ActivityType and ActivitySubtype). Also the results from various ActionLimits should be ANDed. (so in the above example- Out of the 2 Sales PCE, if one of them is not Loan ActivitySubtype, it is excluded).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate through the list of PCE items and add the ones that match the criteria to the list of selected items. In order to generalize to any property of PCE in Java you can use reflection (check for example this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)).